# AdMob показывает тестовый баннер на всех устройствах

Tags: android, google-play, admob

Опубликовал недавно приложение.
Товарищ установил себе и у него почему-то тестовый баннер АдМоба.

Вот мой код:

```
    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-34987643789489349449/497654678"
    />
```

В чем может быть причина ?

Comment: Ну, судя по тому, что всё, вроде, верно, проблема в `adUnitId`. Попробуйте его поменять.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, вот это да! Зашел на адмоб и там какой-то другой adUnitId! Хотя, до этого я от туда копировал!! В общем - спасибо:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, судя по тому, что всё, вроде, верно, проблема в `adUnitId`. Попробуйте его поменять.

Comment: Как-то странно, но в нем дело было. Хотя, до этого проверял его на сайте АдМоба!

Comment: Проблеммы копипасты всегда неожиданны, да)